# Load Json data with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm triing to load a json data with ajax, but it doesn't work. Everytime ajax call the error function and doesn't call the success function.

my AJAX call :

```
$(document).on("click", "#myMovies .btn-update", function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().data("id");

  $.ajax({
   url : 'index.php',
   type : 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data : 'id=' + id + '&action=update',
   success : function(data){
      $('#updateMovie')
            .find('[name="title"]').val(data.title).end()
            .find('[name="list"]').val(data.list).end();
   },
   error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log("error");
      alert(textStatus);
      alert(errorThrown);
   }

  });
});
```

The interessing part of index.php :

```
else if($_POST['action'] == "update") {
   /*getSpecificMovie($_POST['id']);
   $movies = getSpecificMovie();
   $results = Utils::secureMoviesJSON($movies);
   echo $results;*/

   header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
   $array = array(
     'title' => 'test',
     'list' => 'test');
   echo json_encode( $array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
}
```

Anyone know where is my mistake ?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Does it write "error" in console ? What does console.log("error", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); print in the error callback ?

Comment: Not sure but you could try replacing `data : 'id=' + id + '&action=update',` with `data : {'id': id, 'action' : 'update'},`

Comment: Yes the console display error then alert(textStatus) display : "parsererror" and alert(errorThrown) display : "synthaxError : Unexpected token <"

Comment: John C : No it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at the 'JSON_FORCE_OBJECT' option. The data type the request expected is a json string. When adding JSON_FORCE_OBJECT to the json_encode function, the json string is not valid for the request.

```
else if($_POST['action'] == "update") {
   /*getSpecificMovie($_POST['id']);
   $movies = getSpecificMovie();
   $results = Utils::secureMoviesJSON($movies);
   echo $results;*/

   header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
   $array = array(
     'title' => 'test',
     'list' => 'test');
   echo json_encode( $array);
   die();
}
```

Also add a parser for the json to your javascript ([parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)):

```
success : function(data){
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#updateMovie')
            .find('[name="title"]').val(data.title).end()
            .find('[name="list"]').val(data.list).end();
   },
```

Comment: Are you sure the only think printed out by the php script is JSON? Maybe add a die() after the echo to test?

Comment: Yes i'm sure that's why I don't find a solution. If I add die(); ajax don't call success or error function and display in console : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"